# Select_tag question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.11

I'm trying to add a drop-down "sort by" switch to a page.  The page determines how to sort the items in the list by a URL argument (http://.../places?sort=name).  **How would I have a drop-down menu that, when changed, goes to the appropriate page?**

```
"Name"            -> ?sort=name
"Category"        -> ?sort=cat
"Abbreviation"    -> ?sort=abbrev
"Building Number" -> ?sort=num
```

Those ^ are the mappings.  I'm also not sure how to have the drop-down menu say one thing, but submit another.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
options = options_for_select [['Name','name'],['Category','cat'],['Abbreviation','abbrev'],['Building Number','num']]
select_tag :sort, options
```

Basically you build the options out first by passing an Array of 2 element arrays where the first element is your display value, and the second element is the select value. options_for_select will generate all the options for you, which you can then pass to select_tag.

Comment: Thanks.  Part 2 of my question: how do I have the drop-down menu go to the appropriate URL when changed?